# How can I use autolayout with vertical spacing to subview.top but not Top layout Guide

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I use autolayout to set my mapview, and want to have a full screen map.

But somehow I don't know how to set to subview.top

I can only set to Top layout Guide, but I don't want to leave it a space

can anyone help?

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UHG0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tap from dropdown you will see another option like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

select your mapView and add constrains for top, bottom, left and right side like:

[image]

and make sure that "constrain to margins" is uncheck.

Comment: but it'll be set to top layout guide and still don't full screen

Comment: Your mapView's origin x is '0'?